# Does the Histogen Theory apply to plant roots as well as stems?

Tags: botany, theoretical-biology, plant-anatomy, tissue

My school textbook briefly mentions a certain "*Histogen Theory*" (von Hanstein) of plant growth/development. However, I can't find any authoritative source on this matter online.

According to my book, as well as [this site](https://www.embibe.com/learn/biology/concept-histogen-theory-5543), the Histogen Theory is only used to model the development of the shoot (stem) apex.

But according to the [definition on Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/histogen%20theory), the Histogen Theory is applicable to *both* the shoot and root systems.

---

Question:

**Is the Histogen Theory applicable to only shoot apices (as some sources suggest), or does it instead, apply to *both* shoot and root apices?**